# Primefaces Modal Dialog is going below the Media compoenent in IE

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces `p:dialog` with `modal=true` and `p:media` in one single page.
Having Problems with **Internet Explorer**(all the versions):

- My `p:dialog`'s Modal is not hiding the `p:media` and
- My `p:dialog` is going behind/below the `p:media` component when dialog shows up.

Please provide any solutions or JQuery workarounds for this.
Here is the code and Screenshot:

```
<div id="myPdfMedia">
  <p:media value="/resources/myfiles/primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf" width="500px" height="300px">  
    Your browser can't display pdf, <h:outputLink value="/resources/myfiles/primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf">click</h:outputLink> to download pdf instead.  
  </p:media>  
</div>
        
<p:commandButton onclick="dlg.show()" value="Dialog"/>
        
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true" appendToBody="true" width="200px" height="100px" header="My Dialog" >
    This is the dialog
</p:dialog>
```

[image]

*Note: Using Primeface 3.5 and JSF 2.1.13*

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem using the documentviewer from primefaces extensions instead media from primefaces.

Using this:

```
<pe:documentViewer locale="pt" height="#{previewHeight}" value="#{previewComponent.file}">
                        #{text['error.documentviewer']}
</pe:documentViewer>
```

instead this:

```
<p:media value="#{previewComponent.file}" height="#{previewHeight}" width="100%" player="pdf" cache="false">
                        #{text['error.documentviewer']}
</p:media>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use z-index attribute like style="z-index : any value higher than the media z-index".
If you want it to apply for all dialogs then put css code like

```
.ui-dialog{z-index:1005 !important;}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: No that's not helping.

Comment: Did you try setting z-index of dialog more than z-index of media. And can try putting dialog on top of media.